# Mongoid: If possible, how to assign a parent to pre-existing child?

Tags: sinatra, mongoid

In a model definition can you have more than one belongs_to statement? If the answer is no, read no further. I am trying to create three 1-n referenced relationships with mongoid in a sinatra app.

## models

```
class SkillTrack
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :grading_period
  belongs_to :teacher
end

class Student
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  field :nickname
  field :dob, type: Date
  has_many :skill_tracks
end

class GradingPeriod
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :school_year
  field :period_name
  field :signing_date, type: Date
  has_many :skill_tracks
end

class Teacher
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  has_many :skill_tracks
end
```

## routes

```
post "/skill_track/new" do
  form = params[:formdata] # using sinatra form helpers gem
  student = Student.find("#{formdata["student_mongo_id"]}") 
  working = (student.skill_tracks.create).id
  ??? what do I do with working to make it a child of a teacher and of a grading_period?
end
```

## what I have tried

The thing that looked the most promising to me from the [mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many) was:

```
band.member_ids = [ id ] #Set the related document ids.
```

I mucked about in irb and tried lots of variations in my models but I could not set a parent teacher or grading period for the newly created skilltracking object. The student foreign key was set properly on creation. 
I am hoping I have a simple syntax ignorance, but I tried so many variations I wonder if I can do this at all.

## UPDATE:

I just needed to add working.save to David Troyer answer and boom working.

```
post "/skill_track/new" do
 form = params[:formdata]
 student = Student.find("#{formdata["student_mongo_id"]}") 
 working = student.skill_tracks.create
 working.teacher = Teacher.create # or find
 working.grading_period = GradingPeriod.create # or find
 working.save
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe so. If I understand your question correctly, try using some setters on the child SkillTrack document.

```rb
post "/skill_track/new" do
  form = params[:formdata]
  student = Student.find("#{formdata["student_mongo_id"]}") 
  working = student.skill_tracks.create
  working.teacher = Teacher.create # or find
  working.grading_period = GradingPeriod.create # or find
end
```

Dig a little bit further into the **Operations** section of the [mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many) you referenced

Comment: Working.teacher no method error. I need help with syntax. I get the impression setting a field and setting a foreign key are not the same.

Comment: Ordinarily I detest RTFM answers because I always read first. The Mongoid documentation is unnecessarily terse, IMHO.

Comment: That being said, I really did get help from your answer because it reinforced my initial feeling that it should be that easy. Doing it in  irb worked. Doing it in sinatra did not work until I added worked.save.